# No route matches GET root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code for _header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", 'root_path', id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   'root_path' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",   'help_path' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

The "root_path" above should be evaluating to "/" but it doesn't. I am using the michael hartl tutorial

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  resources :users
end
```

rake routes:

```
Richard:sample_app richard$ rake routes
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         static_pages#home
     help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
    about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
  contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
          POST   /signup(.:format)         users#create
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In "/views/layout/_header.html.erb" and _footer.html.erb I was using quotes around "root_path" and "about_path" instead of just the variables. check all similar variables to make sure you aren't quoting them

Comment: How is this different than the answer from sa77?

Answer (score 2):

you should not enclose `root_path` in a quote as it is a route helper method that is evaluated to `/`. just do this:

```
<%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
```

or if you like using quotes then use `"#{root_path}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your root is under `http://<host>/` and not `http://<host>/root_path`. `root_path` is the name of a method which returns the url and not the path itself.

Comment: The problem is I'm using "root_path" as a variable which should evaluate to "/" but it doesnt

Comment: please post your view